# analyze log files using awk

Tags: bash, awk

Hello there I have the following cut of  a log file below:

```
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:39 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_1| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:39 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_1| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:39 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_1| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:42 +0200|185.34.66.225|user_2| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:40 +0200|185.34.66.215|user_3| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:49 +0200|185.34.66.215|user_3| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:49 +0200|185.34.66.215|user_3| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:15:59 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_4| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user changed profile| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:17:50 +0200|185.34.66.205|user_5| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 15:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|user_6| - |user logged in| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 15:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|user_6| - |user changed password| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 15:19:19 +0200|178.56.66.225|user_6| - |user logged off| -
Mon, 22 Mar 2020 13:20:42 +0200|185.34.67.225|user_7| - |user logged in| -
```

the main idea is to get a list of bots who log in, change password, log off in the exact same second & without doing any other action between those 3 actions:
I was able to achieve what I want using the following command:

**`cat /path/to/file | awk '{split($0,a,"|"); print a[3],a[1],a[5]}' | awk '{ print $6,$1,$8,$9,$10 }' | grep -A 1 -B 1 "user changed password" | awk 'seen[$1]++ ==2' | grep "user logged off" | awk '{ print $2}'`**

Output:

```
user_1
user_4
user_6
```

however I would need experts help to shorten my code & make it work as fast as possible in a huge log files

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your solution doesn't work at all on the example you gave. Maybe you copied the wrong code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything in one `awk` call.

```
awk -F'|' '
  BEGIN {
    a[0]="user logged in"
    a[1]="user changed password"
    a[2]="user logged off"
  }
 lastuser!= $3 || lasttime!=$1 || a[expected]!=$5 {
   lasttime=$1
   lastuser=$3
   expected=(a[0]==$5?1:0)
   next
 }
 expected++==2 {
   print $3
 }' path_to_file
```

Answer (score -1):

For your scenario, I think this will work pretty well

```
awk -F\| '{ vtAll[$3";"$1]++; if($5 ~ /user logged in|user logged off|user changed password/) vt[$3";"$1]++; } END { for (i in vt) if(vt[i] == 3 && vtAll[i] == 3) print i }' inputFile
```

To share my logic:

1. I created two arrays, having time and user as index
2. In vtAll, I save how many actions that user has made on that exact time
3. In vt, I check if the action is login, logoff or change pass. If so, I increment it as well
4. After the whole file was read, I check if there were three actions on both arrays. If there is, it means the user logged in, changed pass and logged off at the same time, and nothing else was made by that user.